# Creating a page list from resume and get the first page

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, nltk, spacy

My objective is to rank resumes based on Job description:

For which I have the following task:

Creating a list of pages from resume.

Given multiple resumes, I should be able to break them into pages. Resume can be in either text, doc, docx, pdf or html ?

Following link only works for pdf and only when page break occure:
[PyPDF2 split pdf by pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45144206/pypdf2-split-pdf-by-pages)

Comment: This is too broad and probably will get closed!! Tell us what you have tried, what is the problem you are facing!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no one solution for extracting text from different file types. Try using the package fitz for extracting text from pdf:

```
def extractTextfrompdf(resume):
    try:
        temp = fitz.open("pdf", resume)
        pageCount = temp.pageCount
        resumeText = ["".join(temp.getPageText(i) for i in range(pageCount))][0]
        return resumeText, pageCount
    except (TypeError,ValueError):
        logger.exception("Text extraction from pdf failed.")
        pass
```

You can use python-docx to extract text from docx files. The logic should be pretty similar.

Comment: can we try to use word embedding or TFIDF to do this ?

Comment: Yes you can convert the text output from above function to tf-idf using scikit-learn TfidfVectorizer or word vectors.

Comment: and can I divide a document into array of pages using tfidVectorizer ?